# I am trying to read the content of a file through a python program

Tags: python

The problem is related to the text file path.
As soon as i copy the text file in the directory
of the python program and run it,it runs successfully.
Here is the code->

```
ana=open("C:\Users\HP\Downloads\practice1.txt","r")
pj=ana.read()
ana.close()
pj=pj.splitlines()
print(pj)
for i in pj:
    print(i)
```

The error displayed is->

```
[unicode error] 'unicodeescape'  codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3:truncated\UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Please help!

Comment: Try to add `r` in front of your path -> `(r"C:\Us…")`. This will resolve your issue =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try any of the below :

```
ana=open(r'C:\Users\HP\Downloads\practice1.txt')
ana=open('C:\\Users\\HP\\Downloads\\practice1.txt')
ana=open('C:/Users/HP/Downloads/practice1.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

The backslash character (\) has a special meaning when it appears in a string (or bytes) literal in Python. Backslash is used to *escape* characters that otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself, or the quote character.

```
ana=open("C:\Users\HP\Downloads\practice1.txt","r")
```

In your example, Python is trying to escape the `U`, `H`, `D` and `p` characters because they have backslashes in front of them!

Fortunately, Python provides us with a syntax that allows us to write strings containing literal backslash characters. Both string and bytes literals may optionally be prefixed with a letter 'r' or 'R'; such strings are called *raw strings* and treat backslashes as literal characters.

```
ana=open(r"C:\Users\HP\Downloads\practice1.txt","r")
```

Now the backslash characters are treated as normal characters, and no escaping is attempted.

You can read more about this in the Python reference documentation about literals https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals